# how to use sed to replace values in json file variable value

Tags: bash, sed

I need to use sed to modify the 3rd line in my.json file as line shown below.

How do I replace a changing key value( this example shows "group-1") with the variable value that is assigned to $username?

```
    "name": "group-1",
```

Comment: Be very wary attempting to parse json with general shell tools. There is a very specific tool for this job called `jq` (json query), which handles json and json arrays properly. That said, if `"name"` only appears once in the file, you can safely use the following expression to substitute `$username`, `sed "/\"name\":/s/\(^[^:]*[:][ ]\).*$/\1\"$username\",/"`

Answer (score 7):

You can replace like below

**Linux**

```
 sed -i 's/\"name\":.*/\"name\": '${username}'/g' "/path/to/my.json"
```

**MacOS**

```
   sed -i "" 's/\"name\":.*/\"name\": '${username}'/g' "/path/to/my.json"
```

Comment: Based on the example, it should be `sed 's/"name":.*/"name" : '${username}'/g'` instead. You'll also need to take care of potential extra spaces after the quotes. Goes on to say you shouldn't attempt parsing with the wrong tools.

Comment: it doesn't keep the comma at the end.