# To replace a immediate text after pattern match in Linux shell using sed

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

Content of a json file

```
"iso_checksum": "md5:32fdf4fef4ef"
```

I have stored value of new checksum in a variable v = "4dfv45ffdf"

I want to replace the value after md5: from 32fdf4fef4ef to 4dfv45ffdf
after replace above line in the file should like

```
"iso_checksum": "md5:4dfv45ffdf"
```

32fdf4fef4ef is not fixed value so we can not just replace like below

```
sed -i 's/32fdf4fef4ef/4dfv45ffdf/' file
```

4dfv45ffdf this is also not fixed value so kept in
as $v

Can any please help me to perform the above task

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464280/, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50265987 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090642/, etc.

Comment: One-liner: `v="4dfv45ffdf"; echo '"iso_checksum": "md5:32fdf4fef4ef"' | sed "s/\"md5:[^\"]*\"/\"md5:$v\"/g"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need sed command to replace JSON property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090642/need-sed-command-to-replace-json-property-value)

Comment: Below command solved my purpose  Thanks  Wiktor Stribiżew
sed "/\"name\":/s/\(^[^:]*[:][ ]\).*$/\1\"$username\",/"

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer as below

```
y="4dfv45ffdf"
sed "/\"iso_checksum\":/s/\(^[^:]*[:][ ]\).*$/\1\"md5:$y\",/" file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way

```
awk -v v="4dfv45ffdf" '{gsub("md5:[[:xdigit:]]+","md5:"v);print}' file.json
```

Explanation: replace every `md5:` followed by 1 or more base16-digits using `md5:` concatenated with value of `v`, `print` whole line.